# Copy and paste between Emacs in an X terminal and other X applications

Tags: copy-paste, terminal-emacs, x11, clipboard

I am running Emacs in Gnome-terminal on Ubuntu.

The way I know to copy and paste between emacs and other applications is by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, which I think is by the terminal emulator.

A problem with that is it will copy the line continuation symbol `\` in Emacs.

How can I do that flawlessly? Can you explain why your way works? Thanks.

Btw, I asked [a similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/126577/674) with output of less, which I heard uses vi. If possible, could you also take a look at it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the external utilities [xsel](http://www.vergenet.net/%7Econrad/software/xsel/) or [xclip](http://xclip.sourceforge.net/) (they have mostly the same features, I'll use xsel in this answer) to copy data from or to the X clipboard. To copy to the clipboard, pass the desired content on standard input. When pasting from the clipboard, the content is written to standard output.

To copy the selection to the X clipboard, use `M-| xsel -bi RET` ([`shell-command-on-region`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Shell.html#Shell)). If you want to copy to the X selection (which can be pasted with the middle mouse button), use `xsel -i`. To paste from the X selection, you can use the middle mouse button or `M-1 M-! xsel -o RET` ([`shell-command`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Shell.html#Shell) with a prefix argument to insert the output into the current buffer); make that `xsel -bo` to insert the clipboard content.

If you want to copy and paste automatically to the X selection or clipboard (when available) when running in a terminal under X, like what happens when running in an X window, you can set the variables [`interprogram-cut-function`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Low_002dLevel-Kill-Ring.html#index-interprogram_002dcut_002dfunction-2885) and [`interprogram-paste-function`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Low_002dLevel-Kill-Ring.html#index-interprogram_002dpaste_002dfunction-2885) to functions that call `xsel`. Here's some minimally-tested code to automatically copy to the X clipboard when running in a text terminal under X.

```lisp
(defmacro with-x-environment (&rest body)
  `(let ((process-environment
            (cons (concat "DISPLAY=" (getenv "DISPLAY" (selected-frame)))
                  process-environment)))
     (if (getenv "XAUTHORITY" (selected-frame))
          (setq process-environment
                       (cons (concat "XAUTHORITY=" (getenv "XAUTHORITY" (selected-frame)))
                                  process-environment)))
     ,@body))
(defun x-terminal-copy (text)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert text)
    (with-x-environment
     (call-process-region (point-min) (point-max) "xsel" nil nil nil "-bi"))))
(defadvice x-select-text
  (before x-select-text-in-tty activate)
  "Use xsel to copy to the X clipboard when running in a terminal under X."
  (when (and (eq (framep (selected-frame)) t)
                  (getenv "DISPLAY" (selected-frame)))
    (x-terminal-copy text)))
```

If you want automatic pasting as well, the following code should do it, but in a possibly annoying way: it always considers the X clipboard to be newer than Emacs's internal buffers, so it will always paste from X. You may find it more convenient to bind X pasting to a different key instead.

```lisp
(defun x-terminal-paste ()
  (with-temp-buffer
    (with-x-environment
     (call-process "xsel" nil t nil "-bo"))))
(defadvice x-cut-buffer-or-selection-value
  (before x-cut-buffer-or-selection-value-in-tty activate)
  "Use xsel to paste from the X clipboard when running in a terminal under X."
  (when (and (eq (framep (selected-frame)) t)
                  (getenv "DISPLAY" (selected-frame)))
    (x-terminal-paste text)))
```

Comment: Thanks. Gilles. [Here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/eshell.html) it says "Use Eshell when you want to move text between Emacs and external processes". Can Eshell also accomplish the same thing as what we discussed here?

Comment: @Tim I don't understand the connection between this question and eshell. In eshell, the input and output of processes is normal Emacs buffer text. It has nothing to do with copy-paste between Emacs and other **X** applications.

Answer (score 2):

Gilles's solution actually exists as a package, called `xclip` available from GNU ELPA.  I.e. install it from `M-x list-packages` and then enable it with `M-x xclip-mode RET`.

See also [Clipboard manager will not work in terminal Emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/22271) which is basically the same question.