# Clipboard manager will not work in terminal Emacs

Tags: clipboard

Emacs 25.1.50, GTK+ version 3.18.9 on GNU/Linux, version 4.4.
Gnome-terminal as xterm terminal emulator.

When using clipboard (as in, I copy some text from my operating system/browser), and paste it in Emacs GUI version, it works fine. The GUI Emacs works in pair with the clipboard manager, which is supported by many X desktop environments.

However, when I'm using Emacs with `emacs -nw`, the clipboard seems to be inaccesible from the terminal version of Emacs. When reading the Emacs documentation about clipboard, I tried to let the console Emacs communicate with the clipboard with the following settings:

```
(setq
 x-select-enable-clipboard t
 x-select-enable-primary t
 x-select-request-type '(UTF8_STRING COMPOUND_TEXT TEXT STRING)
 x-stretch-cursor t)
```

Without any luck. Other packages like `simpleclip` will not work in terminal Emacs too. So I'm out of ideas. I'm not sure if this is related with the terminal itself of the console-based Emacs.

Comment: With helpful answers, I got [this solution](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/48207/18577)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NEWS for 25.1 says:

```
*** Killing text now also sets the CLIPBOARD/PRIMARY selection
in the surrounding GUI (using the OSC-52 escape sequence).  This only works
if your xterm supports it and enables the 'allowWindowOps' options (disabled
by default at least in Debian, for security reasons).

Similarly, you can yank the CLIPBOARD/PRIMARY selection (using the OSC-52
escape sequence) if your xterm has the feature enabled but for that you
additionally need to add 'getSelection' to 'xterm-extra-capabilities'.
```

So you probably need to set `allowWindowOps` in your xterm's options (e.g. via xrdb).  For other terminal emulators than `xterm` itself, your mileage will vary.

Another way to attack the problem is with the `xclip` package, available in GNU ELPA, which uses an external program called `xclip`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. How did you figured out that the answer might be in the NEWS section of the 25.1 release? I added `xterm*allowWindowOps: true` in my `.Xresources` and `.Xdefault`, restarted it, without any luck. Do you have another suggestion?

Comment: How widespread is support for those escapes in other terminals?

Comment: I knew because I installed the patch that added this support.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31223710/using-x11-clipboard-in-emacs-instance-inside-gnome-terminal.  The recipe I provide there is for `xterm` rather than for `gnome-terminal`.  My guess is that `gnome-terminal` does not pay attention to X resources.  I don't know if it implements those OSC-52 escapes either.