# Add additional function to cua-mode processing for `C-c`

Tags: key-bindings, terminal-emacs, cua-mode

I'm running `cua-mode`, and I'm trying to override the cua binding for `C-c` so that I can insert a function `somefunc` before passing the baton to the original cua binding which is `cua-prefix-override-handler`.

However, I find I can't override the original cua binding.  *(And even if could, I'm still not sure it would work because `cua-prefix-override-handler` appears to be a tricky function based on timing in a loop.)*

```
;; .emacs
...
(cua-mode t)
...
(defun somefunc--cua ()
  "Run `some-command' and `some-other-command' in sequence."
  (interactive)
  (somefunc))
  (cua-prefix-override-handler))

;; THIS FAILS TO OVERRIDE CUA BINDING FOR C-c
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c") 'somefunc--cua)
```

How can I achieve the desired effect of insert an extra function `somefunct` and then continuing on with the cua processing?

*(Background information about the motivation for this question is [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/48207/18577).)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does

```
(define-key cua--cua-keys-keymap (kbd "C-c <timeout>") 'somefunc)
```

(without wrapping `somefunc`) do what you want it to?

### Investigation

When in CUA mode, the usual method of investigating keybindings, `describe-key` did not work with `C-c` (at least with no selected text), as `C-h k C-c` continued waiting for further input (displaying `C-c-`). Hence, I tried `C-c ?` (if a certain key, say `KEY`, is a prefix-key, then `KEY ?` or `KEY C-h`, will display the keybindings starting with `KEY` (this also works for a sequence of keys — e.g. `C-x n ?`)).

This gave the following relevant information:

```
`cua--ena-cua-keys-keymap' Minor Mode Bindings Starting With C-c:
key             binding
---             -------

C-c <timeout>   copy-region-as-kill
```

which tells us that the relevant keybinding is `C-c <timeout>` and that the keymap in which it's bound is `cua--ena-cua-keys-keymap` (which overrides the global map, so just using `(global-set-key (kbd ("C-c <timeout>")) 'somefunc)` wouldn't work).

Comment: Worked perfectly!  Nice job.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
   (global-set-key [remap copy-region-to-clipboard--cua] 'your-replacement-function)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I'm not sure what `'your-replacement-function` represents in this context.

Comment: @CraigHicks: In your specific case, `somefunc--cua `.

Comment: What I called `somefunc-cue` in this question is a just a name substitution for 'copy-region-to-clipboard--cua` in the previous question (in which I selected your answer as correct).  This question is leftover unanswered part of that question.  I changed the name to make this question more clear.

Comment: @CraigHicks: So 'your-replacement-function would be your custom function to replace the emacs-standard cua funtion that you are remapping.

Comment: I read this documentation on `remap` : https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Remapping-Commands.html .  "... Note that remapping only takes place through active keymaps; for example, putting a remapping in a prefix keymap like ctl-x-map typically has no effect, as such keymaps are not themselves active. In addition, remapping only works through a single level ... ".  The problem is that cua-mode is not usually active, so perhaps cua mode's keytable wouldn't always be modified?  Too hard to think about!